# Practical server side includes with Python on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, server-side-includes, static-files

Is there a decent way to "simulate" server side includes using Python on Google App Engine?

I would really like to split my static html files up into smaller pieces for two reasons:

1. They will be easier to manage from a development perspective
2. HTML that is redundant across multiple pages can be more easily re-used and updates to the HTML will show on all pages instead of having to copy and paste updates

Comment: Whatever template library you choose to use to generate your HTML should make this entirely trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use template library ([Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/) is pre-installed on GAE).
["Getting started" doc provides examples](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/templates.html).

What you want to use instead of SSI is [template inheritance](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#template-inheritance).

Comment: Beware that using templates to serve what are essentially static resources will make serving those resources cost more and take longer.  If you really just want a better way to manage purely static HTML, and the cost of serving those resources matters, you might consider invoking jinja2 or Django templates (or webapp templates, which are the same as DjangO templates) in a script that you run before deploying your app.

Comment: @Guido: Statics are blazing fast, not doubt about it. Also you have possibility to push them into CDN. But your solution seems to be overkill for smaller projects. Anyway, going for super-high performance using statics, I'd rather choose splitting them and using client-side merging. This way widely re-used static parts would stay in the browser's cache (and possibly proxies). BTW. thanks for the Python ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Or use a framework like django, which will help in inheritance of templates.

Comment: Django is full MVC stack, using it just for templates is waste of resources and effort.